# Handling power-off of an embedded board

Tags: linux, embedded, beagleboard

I'm working with an embedded board (a BeagleBoard), running a Linux distribution (Angstrom Linux). I would like to gently halt the operating system when a given button is pushed on the board. What I plan to do is :

1. At the init, launch a "power-off" daemon as root user
2. "power-off" run the magic code to check if a given button is pressed
3. If the button is pressed, "power-off" call "halt"

Before jumping on my text-editor and code that, is there some standard Linux daemon to do that ?

Comment: This would be a better question for Serverfault. Its more of a scripting question and dealing with runlevels.

Comment: I see more my question as an architecture related one : I can do it, but I'm not sure it's the right way, due to my limited experience with embedded boards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `init` daemon (process ID 1) is set up to map the `SIGWINCH` signal to the `kb` ("keyboard request") action, which is free for you to define.  `init` is what maps a ctrl-alt-del key press to a reboot; so it would make sense to have `init` handle your shutdown button too.

To implement this you just need to write a little kernel code to map your "shut down" button to send a `SIGWINCH` to PID 1, then set up the `kb` action to call `shutdown -h` in `/etc/inittab`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the details of your board.. but take a look at the 'hal' daemon.

Comment: HAL is being phased out, fyi.